# Excel run by VSTS agent from Powershell fails for unknown reason

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, azure-devops

this will be weird run.

I'm setting up build process in our VSTS project. Everything works smoothly - the build process is supposed to execute powershell script. Powershell script is executed - but here is the problem.

The script creates Excel process and is supposed to open spreadsheet file. It fails with following error:

```
Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '-correct path-'. There are several possible
reasons:
 The file name or path does not exist.
 The file is being used by another program.
 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
```

Unofrtunately it doesn't make any sense as the file do exist, nobody is doing anything with the spreadsheet and the access is - well I wanted to be sure so everyone full control.

What's even more interesting is that during the build process I had open Process Monitor running - it recorded several accesses of the spreadsheet file by Excel process - but they all ended with "SCUCCESS" - nothing like "ACCESS DENIED".

I'm puzzled because it doesn't make sense. Additionally I can run the script from the user used by VSTS agent directly it there are no issues.

What possibly could interfere with the process?

Comment: private agent? what happens if you try to list contents of the folder using the build? did you try the debug switch? add some logging to the script

Comment: Are you using host build agent or private build agent on vsts, have you double checked the relevant permission of the build service account, it should be the build service account to run the powershell script and   launch excel. If you are using private agent, also try to remote to build agent and run the script directly to narrow down the issue.

Comment: What's your script?

Comment: Does your agent run as an interactive service or not?

Answer (score 0):

For x64 machine,create the following directory: 
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`

Make sure that the agent account has full access control for the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\` folder , `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile` folder and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop` folder.

**More details in:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2012/12/19/error-microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-while-accessing-microsoft-office-11-0-object-library-from-ssis/